# SolutionContext.ConfigurationName set returns E_FAIL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte, vs-extensibility

I have the following code in a custom project based on MPF for Projects - Visual Studio 2010:

```
  EnvDTE.Project dteProj = CurrentProject();
  dteProj.ConfigurationManager.AddConfigurationRow("MyCustomConfig", "Debug", false);
  var solution = dteProj.DTE.Solution as EnvDTE90.Solution3;
  foreach (EnvDTE80.SolutionConfiguration2 solConfig in solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations)
  {
    foreach (EnvDTE.SolutionContext solContext in solConfig.SolutionContexts)
    {
      if (dteProj.UniqueName != solContext.ProjectName)
        continue;

      //Returns E_FAIL 
      solContext.ConfigurationName = "MyCustomConfig";
    }
  }
```

As you can see everything is pretty straight forward. I create a new configuration for my project and want to use it in a solution context. Setting the configuration name returns E_FAIL.

Why is the assignment failing? What is the correct programmatic equivalent for selecting a project configuration for a project from the drop down in the Configuration Manager dialog box?

Thanks